# How to extract netmask using /sbin/ip?

Tags: ip, ifconfig

I want to replace `ifconfig` with `/sbin/ip`. Using `ifconfig` I can see lines like

```
inet addr:xx.xxx.x.xx  Bcast:xx.xxx.x.xx  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

and can easily parse this to find the netmask (255.255.255.0). How can I achieve this using `/sbin/ip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `ip a` you'll get output similar to that which you get running `ifconfig`. Specifically, you'll see a line similar to yours:

```
inet xx.xxx.x.xx/24 brd xx.xxx.x.xx
```

The `/24` denotes the subnet mask in slash notation.